# Convert date format from php to Java?

Tags: java, php, date, simpledateformat

I am working on a Streaming Android application which I have to convert some php codes to java.
How can I convert this date format from php to java?

```
$today = gmdate("n/j/Y g:i:s A");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [date format in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is interpreted like this:

> **n:** Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros
>
> **j:** Day of the month without leading zeros
>
> **Y:** A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
>
> **g:** 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros
>
> **i:** Minutes with leading zeros
>
> **s:** Seconds, with leading zeros
>
> **A:** Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem - AM/PM

and the same [date format in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
String today = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Impressive how you managed to find the solution to your own question in less than a minute! :)

Comment: The point of this question was sharing new knowledge that I achieved. I have just solved my problem yesterday. By the way, thanks for your answer @walen

Answer (score 0):

To get a new `java.util.Date` object from your PHP date string, in Java:

```
String phpDateString = "7/24/2016 12:21:44 am";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
Date javaDate = sdf.parse(phpDateString);

System.out.println(javaDate);
System.out.println(sdf.format(javaDate));
```

Output:

```
Sun Jul 24 00:21:44 CEST 2016
7/24/2016 12:21:44 AM
```

OP's self-answer was very informative, but it had an error in the Java expression (it's lowercase `h` for am/pm hours) and didn't include code to actually parse the PHP string into a Java `Date` object, which was the original question.

Comment: I think you get me wrong! I want to get to the same result in *java* as *php* does using this command **gmdate("n/j/Y g:i:s A")**